# How come I can send a const *this into a non-const method?

Tags: c++

Lets consider the next piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Real
{
   public:
      int re;

      explicit Real(int num = 0)
      {
         re = num;
      }

      Real operator + (const Real& real)
      {
         return Real(re + real.re);
      }

};

int main()
{
   Real real2(4), real3(3);
   Real real4 = (Real)6 + real2 + real3;
   cout << real4.re << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and the output is 13. But, the compiler first reads the operation `(Real)6 + real2`. In this operation, *this is an rvalue, therefore, it is const. So we sent a const *this into a non-const method, which I expected to not compile

Where is the fault in my logic? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think rvalues are const? If they were, move semantics would be impossible.

Comment: @molbdnilo isn't the expression '6' for example isn't const? can you change it?

Comment: `6` is const, but `Real(6)` isn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo Why is that? I can't change Real(6), so why it's not a constant?

Comment: Why do you think you can't change it?

Comment: @molbdnilo Since it doesn't occupy memory and it's just a value floating somewhere, same as with '6'

Comment: "Since it doesn't occupy memory" It does occupy memory.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't occupy memory? Where is "somewhere" if not in memory? (And the `6` also has to be stored, otherwise where would it come from? Magical elves?)

Comment: @molbdnilo You're right, I wasn't accurate - it doesn't point to a specific memoy location which holds a value. It's a temp value, which is gone after the operation is complete. I'll ask you this - How can you change '(Real)6'?

Comment: "it doesn't point to a specific memoy location which holds a value" It does point to a specific memory location. Where do you think `this` points to? "It's a temp value" This does not prevent it from having an address. "which is gone after the operation is complete" This does not prevent it from having an address while it is still there.

Comment: @Suspicious_1 For instance, `Real real4 = Real(6) = Real(100);`. This assigns a new value to the left-hand temporary, and then initializes `real4` with the result. And, as you have noticed, member functions are allowed to change it.

Comment: "How can you change '(Real)6'" You are allowed to call a non-const member function on it.

Comment: @molbdnilo contextually `6` wouldn't be const either.. the expression would create an integer temporary which can be subject of move semantics. But that's not what may happen in machine code, as per as-if rule.

Comment: @molbdnilo This example shattered my understanding of C++'s rvalues and lvalues. Why does this compile, but this isn't:  `int a = 4; 6 = a;`? `Real(6)` is an rvalue, how can we assign to it?

Comment: The simple explanation is class operators behave differently than built-in operators. They are functions with pretty syntax.

Comment: @Suspicious_1 Whether `Real(6)` is an rvalue or not depends on the context. On its own, it's just a temporary object. The difference with literal integers is that literal integers represent temporary *const* objects, but other temporary objects are not const.